# groups and combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A = \{1, 2, ..., 10\}$.

Calculate the number of subsets $B,C \subseteq A$ of size 4 for which $|B \cap C| \leq 1$.

I know that the number of 4 size subsets is $10 \choose 4$.
But it seems to me that there is always a possibility to find two subsets size 4 as asked. which mean, the number of subsets I'm lookin for is also $10 \choose 4$.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it.

Comment: You say that you want to calculate the number of **sets** $B,C$ with.... Don't you mean the number of **ordered pairs** $\langle B,C\rangle$ or otherwise the number of the **unordered pairs** $\{B,C\}$ with $|B\cap C|\leq1$?

Comment: Maybe you're write but I wrote the question the way my proffesor wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

For every fixed subset $B$ you can have either a subset $C$ such that $|B\cap C|=0$ eitehr a subset $C$ such that $|B\cap C|=1$ so the result is
$$
{10\choose4}\times\left[{6 \choose 4} + 4\times {6\choose 3}\right]
$$